# ngx-translate is not working in production mode with Angular 8

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

I am using [ngx-tanslate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) in my angular application for internationalization.

I am facing an issue while running in production mode.

It is always displaying only key.

In dev mode, it works fine when I am running with `ng serve`

I am using `Angular 8` , `ngx-translate/core : 11.0.1` & `ngx-translate/http-loader: 4.0.0`

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to initialize the prefix in my loader so that my i18n folder works fine.

Thanks to [this](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/853#issuecomment-391229882)

Answer (score 0):

First of all be sure the *.json file was copied to assets folder.

for more information see [Angular 6 CLI does not copy library's assets folder into dist folder](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11071)

Comment: ok thank you for your reply. I will check and get back to you.